# Return multileve array from MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return some data from a query in this format (or at least very similar)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Gym Opening Times
            [times] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [label] => Mon-Thu
                            [time] => 6:00am : 10:00pm
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [label] => Fri
                            [time] => 6:00am : 09:00pm
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [label] => Sat & Sun
                            [time] => 6:00am : 10:00pm
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Resteruant Times
            [times] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [label] => Mon-Thu
                            [time] => 6:00am : 10:00pm
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [label] => Fri
                            [time] => 6:00am : 09:00pm
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [label] => Sat & Sun
                            [time] => 6:00am : 10:00pm
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I have this query so far, however, it throws an error **Error executing PDO query: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row**

```
SELECT 
    otg.groupName, 
    otg.id, 
   (SELECT 
        ot.id, 
        ot.label, 
        ot.time 
    FROM 
        opening_times ot 
    WHERE 
        ot.groupId = otg.id) as times
FROM 
    opening_time_groups as otg 
WHERE 
    otg.venueId = $venueId 
    AND otg.active = 1
```

What have I gotten wrong? Or is this something I simply can't do in 1 query?

Comment: You won't be able to get this straight off MySQL. You need to use some driver like Doctrine to get such collections.

Answer (score 0):

You sub query is returning more than one row. A sub query in the SELECT must only return a single row.

However it would seem that you could do this simple with a normal join, then sort the array out in the script that calls it:-

```
SELECT 
    otg.groupName, 
    otg.id, 
    ot.id, 
    ot.label, 
    ot.time 
FROM     opening_time_groups as otg 
LEFT OUTER JOIN opening_times ot 
ON  ot.groupId = otg.id) as times
WHERE otg.venueId = $venueId 
AND otg.active = 1
```